# Rails Polymorphic has_one throwing uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4 I am trying to setup a polymorphic relationship where I have an address model and multiple other models will have one address. I have the following code:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end

class Corporate < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :addressable

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addressable
end
```

In my DB, I have the following:

```
  create_table "addresses", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "line1"
    t.string   "line2"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "zip_code"
    t.string   "contact_person"
    t.string   "contact_number"
    t.integer  "addressable_id"
    t.string   "addressable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "corporates", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

However, when I do

```
@corporate = Corporate.new
@corporate.build_addressable
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Corporate::Addressable)
```

Any idea what the issue is. I followed the rails guide, which had an example of has_many, while I used has_one.

Comment: I think you are missing a class `addressable` I've looked into the rails guide and i think you are trying to achieve what they described using `imagable` ... Just add the addressable model which has many addressees and every thing will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, should be:

```
class Corporate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
end
```